# How to control the behavior of Enter in DrRacket?

Tags: racket

Like when I wrote this line:

```
(rectangle 10 20)
```

and my cursor is at `1`, at this point when I press enter, `0 20)` comes at another line and `(rectangle 1` remains on the first one. This is very frustrating, interpreter of other programming rarely behaves like this, e.g. Python, Ruby.

I want an another behavior, I want that no matter where I am on the line, when I press enter DrRacket should interpret the instruction.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to make the enter key do what you want, but for now, you can use ctrl-enter.

Comment: There might be way to map :/